# Add a listener to a GridPanel that it's already created

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have checked the API and is supposed to exist a method from GridPanel that is addLister, so ok I try to use it:

```
function showCreatePatientCoincidencesWindow(matches, patientData, actuallyCreate) {
    var grid = new GridPanel('idGrid', '', null, 250);
        grid.addColumn(new GridColumn('idgridColumn0LC', 'Nombre', "cName"));
        grid.addColumn(new GridColumn('idgridColumn1LC',' Apellido1', "cSurname1"));
        grid.addColumn(new GridColumn('idgridColumn2LC', 'Apellido2', "cSurname2"));
        grid.addColumn(new GridColumn('idgridColumn3LC', 'Documento', "cDoc"));
        grid.addColumn(new GridColumn('idgridColumn4LC', 'Fecha Nacimiento', "cDate"));
        grid.addColumn(new GridColumn('idgridColumn5LC', 'Sexo', "cGender"));
        grid.addListener('show',showHandler,this);     
    var gridStore = new Ext.data.GroupingStore({
        root:'matches',
        reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
        .
        .
        .
        .
```

The code before is the one I'm executing, it obviously continue but the problem is that I get this error from chrome debugger:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object #GridPanel has no method 'addListener'

How is it possible? what I'm doing wrong? My library is the 3.4 and I have check the APIs of Ext JS 2.3, 3.4 and 4.1, all of them have this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your gridpanel constructor is not formatted properly [per the 3.4 docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.grid.GridPanel-method-constructor).

There should only be a single argument which is a config *object* (i.e. with config keys and wrapped in curlies `{}`).

Also full names are customary `Ext.grid.GridPanel` vs `GridPanel`. I think you can get around that if you are requiring the `Ext.grid.GridPanel.js` in your JS but I can't tell if you are doing that.

I probably do not have your arguments mapped to the right configs correctly, but this should give you an idea:

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({id: 'idGrid', title: '', data: null, width: 250});
```

You may also want to define the columns and store in the constructor while your at it:

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    id: 'idGrid', 
    title: '', 
    data: null, 
    width: 250,
    columns: [{
        id: 'idgridColumn0LC',
        header: 'Nombre',
        field: 'cName'
    }, {
        id: 'idgridColumn1LC',
        header: 'Apellido1',
        field: 'cSurname1'
    }, {
        id: 'idgridColumn2LC',
        header: 'Apellido2',
        field: 'cSurname2'
    }, {
        id: 'idgridColumn3LC',
        header: 'Documento',
        field: 'cDoc'
    }, {
        id: 'idgridColumn4LC',
        header: 'Fecha Nacimiento',
        field: 'cDate'
    }, {
        id: 'idgridColumn5LC',
        header: 'Sexo',
        field: 'cGender'
    }],
    store: new Ext.data.GroupingStore({
        root:'matches',
        reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
            // reader configs
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much Geronimo, you are right I just notice that my class is not the one from Ext, is one something Wrapping the one from Ext.

I'm working in a big project that had a lot of development before I started with it, and I'm still discovering this kind of things, I got confused because the name of the wrapping class is exactly the same as the Ext's

But one time more, thank you for the effort and the code you made for me!